# How to differentiate color scheme

Tags: colors, sublimetext2

I would like to change color scheme `Eiffel` so that the keyword `class` in java files will be different color than keyword `int`? If I change `Storage` in Eiffel, both keywords change the color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the exact scopes of `class` and `int`. The [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) is a great way to open files inside `.sublime-package` files.

Once installed, launch *”PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, open the Java package and look for the syntax files (e.g.`Java.sublime-syntax`).

I'm not familiar enough with Java, but it looks to me like `class` uses the scope `meta.class` and `int` uses `storage.type.primitive.array`. That means, that in your theme you would at least have to change `meta` or `storage`. Needless to say that you can be more specific than that.

Comment: OP is asking about ST2, before `.sublime-syntax`, before PRV was needed, and before the Java language definition was rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Using a nice little plugin called [`ScopeAlways`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways), you can see in the status bar the full scope underlying your cursor (if you have multiple cursors, it just uses the first one). In Sublime Text 2, using the following code:

```java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        int integer = 13;
    }
}
```

The word `class` is scoped as `storage.modifier.java`, whereas `int` is scoped as `storage.type.primitive.array.java` (I removed a few unimportant extraneous scopes from each for clarity). So, in your theme, you could have one color for `storage.modifier`, and another for `storage.type`, to differentiate between `class` and `int`. Be aware, however, that many other keywords will fall under both scopes, so your custom colors won't **just** highlight those particular words.

Good luck!